# Need help with probability question

Tags: probability

Mr. A, B, C, and D are all telling the truth 70% of the time.  Mr. A made some personal statement, then Mr. D said that Mr. C said that Mr.B said, that A was telling the truth.  Given the statement of Mr. D, what is the (conditional) probability that Mr. A was actually telling the truth?

Assuming independence, I am getting P(A telling truth) = 0.7, but that does not seem right.

Comment: Mr A tells the truth 70% of the time, but Mr B actually "vouched" for Mr A. That should have an impact so it's seems more complicated that that.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  I would expect that the actual probability is higher than 70%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to convert the event $E := $ "D said C said B said A told the truth" into one involving A,B,C,D telling the truth or not in some combinations. Let's define events:

\begin{eqnarray*}
A_t &=& \text{$A$ told the truth} \\
B_t &=& \text{$B$ told the truth} \\
C_t &=& \text{$C$ told the truth} \\
D_t &=& \text{$D$ told the truth.} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Firstly, consider the event "B said A told the truth". This can happen in two ways:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\text{$A,B$ both tell the truth} && \qquad\text{i.e. $A_t \cap B_t$} \\
\text{$A,B$ both lie} && \qquad\text{i.e. $A_t^c \cap B_t^c$.}
\end{eqnarray*}

Next, consider the event "C said B said A told the truth". This can happen in four ways:

\begin{eqnarray*}
&& A_t \cap B_t \cap C_t \\
&& A_t \cap B_t^c \cap C_t^c \\
&& A_t^c \cap B_t \cap C_t^c \\
&& A_t^c \cap B_t^c \cap C_t. \\
\end{eqnarray*}

You might realise that in every case, the event occurs when an even number of lies are told (to cancel each other out, in a sense).

So we find that event $E$ can occur eight ways: all the ways in which an even number of lies are told:

\begin{eqnarray*}
&& A_t \cap B_t \cap C_t \cap D_t \\
&& A_t \cap B_t \cap C_t^c \cap D_t^c \\
&& A_t \cap B_t^c \cap C_t \cap D_t^c \\
&& A_t \cap B_t^c \cap C_t^c \cap D_t \\
&& A_t^c \cap B_t \cap C_t \cap D_t^c \\
&& A_t^c \cap B_t \cap C_t^c \cap D_t \\
&& A_t^c \cap B_t^c \cap C_t \cap D_t \\
&& A_t^c \cap B_t^c \cap C_t^c \cap D_t^c. \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Since $E$ is the union of those eight disjoint events, $P(E)$ is the sum of their respective probabilities:

$$P(E) = (0.7)^4 + 6 \times (0.7)^2(0.3)^2 + (0.3)^4 = \dfrac{1282}{2500}.$$

Choosing from those eight events, those where $A_t$ occurs, we get:

$$P(E \cap A_t) = (0.7)^4 + 3 \times (0.7)^2(0.3)^2 = \dfrac{931}{2500}.$$

Therefore,

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(A_t \mid E) &=& \dfrac{P(E \cap A_t)}{P(E)} \\
&=& \dfrac{931}{1282} \\
&\approx& 0.7262.
\end{eqnarray*}